# Ubuntu 18,04 automatically wakes up from suspension and heat up my world

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, overheating, macosx

I just put Ubuntu 18.04 on Mac Air2017 (good riddance!). It's been working fine but I have a nagging issue.

After I put the lid down, ubuntu suspends. But it wakes up intermmitantly and again go to sleep but sometimes it doesn't and it heats up my back-pack. I don't how to even start debugging this problem.

Following is the output of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 6000 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:15.0 DMA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Serial IO DMA Controller (rev 03)
00:15.4 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Serial IO GSPI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Multimedia controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
04:00.0 SATA controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a801 (rev 01)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5320 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 2C 2013]
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5320 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 2C 2013]
06:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5320 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 2C 2013]
06:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5320 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 2C 2013]
06:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5320 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 2C 2013]
06:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5320 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 2C 2013]
07:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation DSL5320 Thunderbolt 2 NHI [Falcon Ridge 2C 2013]
```

I also installed `tlp` and `powertop`. Both of them starts at bootup.

Comment: check cron jobs. also it cloud be issue with video driver. you need check system logs.